# Assigning an array as a value of another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, delimiter

I have three arrays i need to create an array which can be multidimensional.

### 1st array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Test_One
    [1] => Test_two
)
```

### 2nd array

```
Array
(
   [0] => www.link.com
   [1] => www.link2.com
)
```

### 3rd array

```
Array
(
   [0] => Song1
   [1] => song2
)
```

### What i want

```
Array
(
   [www.link.com] => Array
                     (
                        [0] => Test_one
                        [1] => Song1
                     )
   [www.link2.com] => Array
                     (
                        [0] => Test_two
                        [1] => Song2
                     )
 )
```

Comment: and what you have tried so far?

Comment: So is the relationship the matching keys? Is there always the same number of elements in each array?

Comment: Is all three arrays of same length?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have same number of elements in all three arrays:

```
<?php
$arr1 = Array
(
    0 => "Test_One",
    1 => "Test_two"
);

$arr2 = Array
(
    0 => "www.link.com",
    1 => "www.link2.com"
);

$arr3 = Array
(
    0 => "Song1",
    1 => "Song2"
);

$final = []; //for versions below PHP 5.4 use $final = array();

foreach($arr2 as $key=>$value) {
    $final[$value] = [$arr1[$key],$arr3[$key]];
}

print_r($final);
```

will output:

```
Array
(
    [www.link.com] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test_One
            [1] => Song1
        )

    [www.link2.com] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test_two
            [1] => Song2
        )

)
```

**Update:** Simplified `foreach` loop. From Comments @uchiha

Comment: You can simplify that `foreach($arr2 as $key=>$value) {
    $final[$value][] = $arr1[$key];
    $final[$value][] = $arr3[$key];
}` into `foreach($arr2 as $key=>$value) {
    $final[$value] = [$arr1[$key],$arr3[$key]];
}`

Comment: Yeah it can be :) [Updated]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you havn't same number of elements in all three arrays:

```
<?php
$arr1 = Array
(
    0 => "Test_One",
    1 => "Test_two"
);

$arr2 = Array
(
    0 => "www.link.com",
    1 => "www.link2.com"
);

$arr3 = Array
(
    0 => "Song1",
);

$final = []; //for versions below PHP 5.4 use $final = array();

foreach($arr2 as $key=>$value) {
    if(array_key_exists($key,$arr1)) {
        $final[$value][] = $arr1[$key];
    }
    if(array_key_exists($key,$arr3)) {
        $final[$value][] = $arr3[$key];
    }
}

print_r($final);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [www.link.com] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test_One
            [1] => Song1
        )

    [www.link2.com] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test_two
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help :)

```
<?php 
$array1 = Array
(
    'Test_One',
    'Test_two'
);


$array2 = Array
(
   'www.link.com',  
   'www.link2.com'
);

$array3 = Array
(
   'Song1',
  'song2'
);

$array4 = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($array2 as $a2){
    $array4[$a2][] = $array1[$i];
    $array4[$a2][] = $array3[$i];
    $i++;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array4);
?>
```